# DB2 multiple on delete triggers causing deadlock

Tags: db2

When trying to run a delete query on the parent table I am getting locked. Following is the table structure and executing this *" DELETE FROM PARENT WHERE PARENT_ID = 1; "* would create a deadlock -

------------------Create related tables-----------------------------

```
CREATE TABLE PARENT (
    PARENT_ID INT NOT NULL,
    PARENT_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE CHILD_ONE (
    CHILD_ONE_ID INT NOT NULL,
    CHILD_ONE_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SELF_REFERNCE_ID INT,
    LANGUAGE_ID INT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE CHILD_TWO (
    CHILD_TWO_ID INT NOT NULL,
    CHILD_ONE_ID INT NOT NULL,
    QUANTITY INT,
    LANGUAGE_ID INT NOT NULL
);
```

-----------------------Create indexes on tables-----------------------------

```
ALTER TABLE PARENT ADD CONSTRAINT PARENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (PARENT_ID);
ALTER TABLE CHILD_ONE ADD CONSTRAINT CHILD_ONE_PK PRIMARY KEY (CHILD_ONE_ID,LANGUAGE_ID);
ALTER TABLE CHILD_ONE ADD CONSTRAINT CHILD_ONE_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (CHILD_ONE_ID) REFERENCES PARENT (PARENT_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE CHILD_ONE ADD CONSTRAINT SELF_REFERNCE_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (SELF_REFERNCE_ID) REFERENCES PARENT (PARENT_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE CHILD_TWO ADD CONSTRAINT CHILD_TWO_PK PRIMARY KEY (CHILD_TWO_ID,LANGUAGE_ID);
ALTER TABLE CHILD_TWO ADD CONSTRAINT CHILD_TWO_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (CHILD_TWO_ID) REFERENCES PARENT (PARENT_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE CHILD_TWO ADD CONSTRAINT CHILD_ONE_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (CHILD_ONE_ID) REFERENCES PARENT (PARENT_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

-----------------------------Create triggers tables-----------------------------

```
CREATE TRIGGER CHILD_ONE_TRIGGER AFTER DELETE ON CHILD_ONE 
REFERENCING OLD AS O FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM PARENT WHERE PARENT_ID = O.CHILD_ONE_ID;

CREATE TRIGGER CHILD_TWO_TRIGGER AFTER DELETE ON CHILD_TWO
REFERENCING OLD AS O FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM PARENT WHERE PARENT_ID = O.CHILD_TWO_ID;
```

---------------Insert Records--------------------------------------------

```
INSERT INTO PARENT (PARENT_ID, PARENT_NAME) VALUES (1,'CHILD_ONE-1');
INSERT INTO PARENT (PARENT_ID, PARENT_NAME) VALUES (2,'CHILD_ONE-2');
INSERT INTO PARENT (PARENT_ID, PARENT_NAME) VALUES (3,'CHILD_ONE-3');
INSERT INTO PARENT (PARENT_ID, PARENT_NAME) VALUES (4,'CHILD_TWO-1');
INSERT INTO PARENT (PARENT_ID, PARENT_NAME) VALUES (5,'CHILD_TWO-2');

INSERT INTO CHILD_ONE (CHILD_ONE_ID, CHILD_ONE_NAME, SELF_REFERNCE_ID, LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (1,'CHILD_ONE-1', NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO CHILD_ONE (CHILD_ONE_ID, CHILD_ONE_NAME, SELF_REFERNCE_ID, LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (1,'CHILD_ONE-1', NULL, 2);
INSERT INTO CHILD_ONE (CHILD_ONE_ID, CHILD_ONE_NAME, SELF_REFERNCE_ID, LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (2,'CHILD_ONE-2', 1, 1 );
INSERT INTO CHILD_ONE (CHILD_ONE_ID, CHILD_ONE_NAME, SELF_REFERNCE_ID, LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (3,'CHILD_ONE-3', 2, 2 );

INSERT INTO CHILD_TWO (CHILD_TWO_ID, CHILD_ONE_ID, QUANTITY, LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (4, 1, 501, 1);
INSERT INTO CHILD_TWO (CHILD_TWO_ID, CHILD_ONE_ID, QUANTITY, LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (5, 2, 501, 1);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: What you see is not a deadlock since all lock's are owned by the same agent. Instead you are creating an infinite loop of cascading deletes that fires delete triggers that cascade delete etc. I would have expected that the call stack would blow up rather soon, but on my 10.5 express-c it runs until I killed it with ipclean. Can you explain why you need to delete both ways?

Comment: John, I'll add your comment from my removed answer here: " I want to clear off all rows from parent which doesn't have any references, these child tables are kind of resources and resources are dependent on each other. The parent table I am using is used to generate id's for all resources. Say there are two resources House and Kitchen, then there would be two rows in child_one house without any parent and kitchen with house as parent. Consider new resource dining table with quantity 10 and parent kitchen, so when I delete a house ideally everything must be deleted."

Comment: What is the purpose of CHILD_TWO? In your HOUSE, KITCHEN scenario above, what would be in that table?

Comment: The CHILD_ONE table has entries which don't need to be quantified. CHILD_TWO table has entries which are quantifiable and also there are some more attributes like resource_type, installed_date etc.